# Error Connecting to PostgreSQL on Red Hat Openshift gear

Tags: postgresql, openshift, psql

Permit my noobishness, I'm learning how to work with Linux Openshift. While following a book, I tried to connect to the server online from the command line [Bash]. I ran
`rhc port-forward`
and it displayed:

`Checking available ports ... done`

`Forwarding ports ...`

`To connect to a service running on OpenShift, use the Local address`

`Service    Local               OpenShift`

`---------- -------------- ---- ---------------`

`httpd      127.0.0.1:8080  =>  127.7.74.1:8080`

`postgresql 127.0.0.1:5432  =>  127.7.74.2:5432`

`Press CTRL-C to terminate port forwarding`

The book said I should run
`psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5433 -U username password`

Now why does bash complain anytime I run the command,

`psql -h 127.0.0.1 ...`
It says, psql command not found.

Comment: Git? As in source-control? What git has to do with psql? You really should post the whole command.

Comment: This is the whole command I wrote in git. After navigating to my working folder, I wrote: psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5433 -U myUsername myAppName. And I get an error that sh.exe" psql command is not found.

Comment: No, you don't write it in git, check what git is. You probably mean MINGW. Check what tools you use and what they are.

Comment: I already ran the previous comment in git, the tutorial didn't say I should change the write pad. Have you ever written an application in openshift please?

Comment: Please refer to git documentation http://git-scm.com/documentation  It should help you understand what git is and what it is not.

Comment: I've sent a mail to git. I think they are working on it. I've still not found a solution to it but I'll surely update you when I find a solution. Still on it.

Comment: Finally, I got it working. What happened initially was that I ought to have installed postgreSQL and copied it to my working directory in git. Not only can you use the git command line for version control/source control but there's a lot more you can do with it. I was actually connecting with my gear online on openshift from the git command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my internet connection breaks off at some point while I am cloning to my local machine. Thank you all for you contribution. It needs a strong internet connection and it takes quite a time to clone: https://github.com/postgres/postgres.git.

Answer (score 0):

check and make sure that you have psql installed on your local machine. If not use a package manager like yum (fedora/RHEL) or Brew (Mac) to install the necessary binaries to get the psql command.